# PSTtricks: Positioning axeslabels

Tags: pstricks, pst-plot

I am trying to position my axes labels using PStricks, see this MWE:

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=60pt, 10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pstricks,pst-plot}   
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\psset{xAxisLabel=$x/r_0$, yAxisLabel=$y/r_0$,xAxisLabelPos={3in,-0.425in},yAxisLabelPos={-3in,-0.4in}}

\begin{psgraph}[axesstyle=frame, Dx=20, Dy=0.005, Oy={0.990}, Ox={0}](0,0.990)(100,1.010025){7.0cm}{6.0cm}%

\end{psgraph}    
\end{document}
```

I want the x-axis label to be right next to the x-axis. Similarly, I want the y-axis label to be right above the y-axis. Both should be horizontal. Following the manual of `pst-plot`, I try to do this by specifying the coordinates of the axeslabels manually, but my y-axis label is out of the picture and I can't find any coordinate-values that recover it.

Is there a more systematic way to do this than just guessing?

---

EDIT: What I am aiming for is to have the axes labels positioned as in the following example, but the y-axis should run from 0.99..1.01 in steps of 0.005

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not really undetstand what you need. However, if it cannot be dont with the
default optional argument then use `\rput` or `\uput`

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=60pt, 10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot}   
\begin{document}    

\psset{xAxisLabel=, yAxisLabel=}
\begin{psgraph}[axesstyle=frame, Dx=20, Dy=0.005, Oy={0.990}, Ox={0}](0,0.990)(100,1.010025){7.0cm}{6.0cm}%
\uput[90](0,1.01){$y/r_0$}\uput[0](100,0.99){$x/r_0$}       
\end{psgraph}    

\end{document}
```

Comment: I added a picture to show what I am trying to do. Is there a way to specify it so it is plotted like that automatically, or do I have to use `rput`?

Comment: see edited answer: `\uput[angle](x,y){...}`